# How to evaluate this expression through the Java AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I'm trying to use the AWS API for DynamoDB from Java. For some Scan operations, I want to use filters like this:

(NAME BEGINS_WITH "Joe") AND ((SALARY < 100) OR (AGE > 60))

that is, combining and nesting the AND/OR boolean operators. Nonetheless, I have only find how to pass with which operator to evaluate the list of ScanFilters, but not how to combine them to build a more complicated expression. So, how to do this kind of expressions? Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
   .withMyNiceExpression("(NAME BEGINS_WITH \"Joe\") AND ((SALARY < 100) OR (AGE > 60))");
```

Thanks.

P.S.: the model of the table is unknown to me and dynamic. That's why I have to use the API in such way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [doc for Table scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html) you should see an example under Specifying Optional Parameters.

The map `expressionAttributeValues` can take as many attributes as you want and you can create a condition such as (ATT1 > :val1 AND (ATT2 < :val2 OR ATT2 > :val3))

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to use inside the filter expression BEGINS_WITH and others?

Comment: begins_with is available:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html